# Output the result of a SELECT executed on IBM DB2

Tags: sql, t-sql, db2, db2-400

It's easy to do it using T-SQL (SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @MyStatement AS NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE'
EXEC (@MyStatement)
```

However, I've spend hours on IBM DB2 without being able to do the same. I was hoping this would work:

```
DECLARE myStatement VARCHAR(1000);
SET myStatement = 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE';
PREPARE s1 FROM myStatement;
EXECUTE s1;
```

But I get the following error message:

> Elément syntaxique VARCHAR n'est pas correct. Eléments possibles :
>   DYNAMIC SENSITIVE ASENSITIVE INSENSITIVE.. SQLCODE=-104,
>   SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60

which I would translate to:

> Syntax element VARCHAR is incorrect. Possible elements: DYNAMIC
>   SENSITIVE ASENSITIVE INSENSITIVE.. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
>   DRIVER=4.18.60

Comment: What client are you using to connect and display the data?

Comment: declare x as char(1000); set x = 'select * from mytable'; execute immediate x;

Comment: You're looking for [compound SQL statements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcompounddynstmt.htm)

Comment: @xQbert: SSRS 2016 and also IBM SQL and Routine Development (IBM Data Studio)

Comment: @danny117, it gives me the following error: the word AS is not well placed

Comment: I just typed in.  As takeout

Comment: What happens if you just run the select statement without the prepare and execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try again using the following :

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE myStatement VARCHAR(1000);
  SET myStatement = 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE myStatement ;
END;
```